# Access Adwords through GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I want to manage my Adwords campaigns through a script. I have a few Adwords scripts running and this is all fine, but now I need to access a library. Unfortunately this is not possible from the Adwords script interface so I need to access my Adwords MCC from the "normal" scripts interface.

Through resources - advanced google services , I don't come across a Google Adwords API. Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is not (yet) supported.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-scripts/G2GiGMp5Ols

Answer (score 0):

Unfornately, AdWords is not available in Advanced Google Services. But you can try communicating using [External APIs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external).

```
var url = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?'
    + 'q=skateboarding+dog'
    + '&start-index=21'
    + '&max-results=10'
    + '&v=2';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
Logger.log(response);
```

> **Making requests to services with OAuth**
>
> APIs that act on behalf of a user usually require authorization, often using the [OAuth protocol](http://oauth.net/). Apps Script doesn't provide built-in support for the protocol, but there are open source libraries you can use to perform the OAuth flow and send the credentials with your requests:
>
> - [OAuth1 for Apps Script](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1): Compatible with OAuth 1.0 and 1.0a.
> - [OAuth2 for Apps Scrip](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2)t: Compatible with OAuth2.

Hope this helps.